# How to add % symbol to Y axis values in HighChart graph?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

[image]

I'm trying to add % after the `100` or `-100` yAxis in the chart above.

I tried to add the % symbols like so:

```
quotes.data.frequency_counts[i].negative = Math.round(negative * -1)+'%';
quotes.data.frequency_counts[i].positive = Math.round(positive)+'%';
```

However got an error saying strings are not allowed as data_points, which makes sense, but still hoping there is a way to get the % sign displayed so the user knows what we are showing them.

This isn't my app, however it is a HighChart that is editable in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8mDQD1?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) for that:

```
yAxis: { 
  title: { text: 'Temperature (Celsius)' } ,
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's an updated (now nonsensical) Plunker showing the changes](http://plnkr.co/edit/C4F72kx3xyCEdt9DCAip?p=preview)